# Is it possible to create a character array within a strcpy?

Tags: c, string, memory, initialization, strcpy

Is it possible to copy a string using C's `strcpy` without first assigning memory to a `char *character_array`?

Basically, is something like this possible:

```
strcpy(char *my_string, another_string);
```

where `my_string` becomes an initialised string with the same length and content as `another_string`.

Comment: Is [`strdup`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) what you are looking for?

Comment: It is! I've heard it's unsafe; why is that?

Comment: I don't know. You might ask that question those people where you heard it.

Comment: @Connor *I've heard it's unsafe* Who told you it's unsafe?  Did they tell you `strlen()` is unsafe, too?  Did they tell you to replace it with vendor-specific code?

Comment: @Connor: That function is only part of POSIX and not yet ISO C (i.e. standard C). However, it will very likely be part of ISO C23, which will likely be published this year. Another thing that may make it dangerous is that you should call `free` on the memory when you no longer need it, otherwise you have a [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

Comment: It is not unsafe per se. It only requires the programmer to remember that the returned pointer must be passed to `free()`.

Comment: C23 is pretty much set at this point so we can start recommending `strdup`. And the only risk is memory leaks indeed, assuming that you pass sanitized data to the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`strcpy` never allocates memory.  The destination must be a pointer to enough, writable, validly-allocated memory, and *you* are responsible for making sure that the destination memory is validly allocated, long enough, and writable.

So these are all okay:

```
char *another_string = "hello";
char my_string_1[20];
strcpy(my_string_1, another_string);     /* valid (plenty of space) */

char my_string_2[6];
strcpy(my_string_2, another_string);     /* valid (just enough space) */

char my_string_3[] = "world";
strcpy(my_string_2, another_string);     /* valid (just enough space) */

char buf[6];
char *my_string_4 = buf;
strcpy(my_string_4, another_string);     /* valid (via intermediate pointer) */

char *my_string_5 = malloc(6);
strcpy(my_string_5, another_string);     /* valid (assuming malloc succeeds) */

char *my_string_6 = malloc(strlen(another_string) + 1);
strcpy(my_string_6, another_string);     /* valid (assuming malloc succeeds) */
```

But these are not valid:

```
char my_string_7[5];
strcpy(my_string_7, another_string);     /* INVALID (not enough space) */

char *my_string_8 = "world";
strcpy(my_string_8, another_string);     /* INVALID (destination not writable) */

char *my_string_9;
strcpy(my_string_9, another_string);     /* INVALID (destination not allocated) */

char *my_string_10 = malloc(20);
free(my_string_10);
strcpy(my_string_10, another_string);    /* INVALID (no longer allocated) */

char *exceptionally_bad_allocator()
{
    char local_buffer[20];
    return local_buffer;
}

char *my_string_11 = exceptionally_bad_allocator();
strcpy(my_string_11, another_string);    /* INVALID (not validly allocated) */
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible using `strcpy` but it is possible to write your own function

```
//if buff is NULL then it will allocate memory for it.
char *strcpyalloc(char *buff, const char *src)
{
    size_t len;
    if(!buff)  // if not allocated allocate
    {
        len = strlen(src) + 1;
        buff = malloc(len);
        if(buff)
        {
            memcpy(buff, src, len);
        }
    }
    else strcpy(buff, src);
    return buff;
}


int main(void)
{
    char *str = NULL;

    str = strcpyalloc(str, "Hello World!");
    if(str) printf("\"%s\"\n", str);
    free(str);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Me4GEr5dP

Comment: IMO I'd be really careful with a design like this.  "Sometimes it `malloc()`'s memory, sometimes it doesn't" is not a feature I'd want buried in a function.

Answer (score 1):

When variable length arrays [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) are supported, code can create right-sized space that is valid *until the end of the block*.

```
{
  char my_string[strlen(another_string) + 1];
  strcpy(my_string, another_string);
  ...
  // No need to free `my_string`
}
```